# Regex exclude slash character

Tags: regex, url

I have the following (dummy) strings, that in reality are part of URLs:

```
methods/english
methods/english/dummy
```

I want my regex to exclude strings that have a slash after `english`. So the second string should not match the regex.

I tried this regex:

```
/methods/.*/[^/]
```

So that it excludes the slash character.

But with this logic it still matches with `methods/english/dummy`. I can't figure out why.

Comment: If tool you are sing supports negative lookaheads, you can use [`^(?!.*english\/).+`](https://regex101.com/r/ueRBr6/1)

Comment: Sounds like you want `^methods/[^/]+$`. String starts with `methods/`, and then contains one or more chars other than `/` till end of string.

Comment: Your attempt looks for a string which has a slash followed by a character which is not a slash. This only excludes strings which contain nothing or another slash after the slash.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your response, it looks very logical but when I tried it in my regex debugger it still doesn't exclude the second string.. It matches with both

Comment: What is your regex debugger? Do you know how to use it? Try in the real environment first. Most people fail to use "regex debuggers" correctly with negated character classes in the pattern, trust me.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/98cNlk/1, what is wrong here?

Comment: Any feedback? Did you have a chance to check in the real environment?

Comment: Hey @WiktorStribiżew, thanks for your feedback. You are right; I just tested again and the regex works in this way. My bad! Thanks for your help

Comment: So, did it help or do you need more assitance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^methods/[^/]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/98cNlk/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `methods/` - a literal string
- `[^/]+` - one or more chars other than `/`
- `$` - end of string.